# Meteor observe on users cursor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm currently have pub/sub method for users like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");

Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
     return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
});
```

And this works fine. But I have problems if I want to add few fields in profile in observe callbacks, like this:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
    var self = this;
    var users = Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1}});

    var subHandle = users.observe({
        added: function (fields) {
            fields.profile.postCount = Post.find({'owner': fields._id}).count();
            self.added("userData", fields._id, fields);
        },
        changed: function(newObj, oldObj){
            fields.profile.postCount = Post.find({'owner': fields._id}).count();
            self.changed("userData", newObj._id, newObj);
        },
        removed: function(obj) {
            self.removed("userData", obj._id);
        }
    });

    self.ready();

    self.onStop(function () {
        subHandle.stop();
    });

});
```

Problem is that when I try to find users on client side, I can find only one user, myself if I'm logged in (`Meteor.users.find().fetch()` inside console). And I saw that publication is finished (Network WS section inside console), so I know that more than one users is pushed to client side.

So I obviously doing something wrong, can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Try checking in the `userData` collection on client-side. You gotta create it first.

Comment: The observe functions run asynchronously, so you're calling ready() before the callbacks had a chance to run. The user documents should still eventually show up on the client, just after the ready message.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one issue here, but what catches my eye is the fact that you are using the publication's name in your `added`/`changed`/`removed` callbacks instead of the collection name (`'users'`). Try modifying your `observe` as follows:

```js
var subHandle = users.observe({
    added: function (fields) {
        fields.profile.postCount = Post.find({'owner': fields._id}).count();
        self.added('users', fields._id, fields);
    },
    changed: function(newObj, oldObj){
        fields.profile.postCount = Post.find({'owner': fields._id}).count();
        self.changed('users', newObj._id, newObj);
    },
    removed: function(obj) {
        self.removed('users', obj._id);
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll examine it further.